# Libgdx opengl draw lines example

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

Can I ask how to draw three not connected non-orthogonal lines using opengl in libgdx? The code snippet is really appreciated. 
I googled it a lot, found sort of example (triangle) [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/My-First-Triangle-(Example)), but it marked as outdated and use meshes.

Opengl tutorial says that I can render line just writing this:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(.25,0.25);
    glVertex2f(.75,.75);
glEnd();
```

But how I can call this code from libgdx?

Is it possible to draw line without meshes and shaders writing?

Even with shader when I write this code to shader and load it thru ShaderProgram(), it just gives compilation error.

```
void main()
{
        glVertex2f(.25,0.25);
        glVertex2f(.75,.75);
}
```

So, while opengl tutorial says I can call this glVertex2f(.25,0.25), I cannot do it from shader.

Lwjgl tutorial somewhat referencing libgdx, like [here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/OpenGL-Line-Rendering)  and [here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/Batching-Rectangles-and-Lines), but code doesn't work in libgdx [method batch.draw(texture, x, y, width, thickness) simly absent in libgdx].

ShapeRenderer is too slow for my use case. 
Rendering line from 1x1 px texture sounds reasonable, but if only I could make opengl calls like above from libgdx, that would be much better. Thank you.

UPD: I saw that it is possible to refer to opengl methods thru `Gdx.gl.xxx()`, but the `Gdx.gl.glVertex2f()` is absent here.

Comment: How did you determine that ShapeRenderer is too slow?

Comment: I parse an svg image once during the scene construction, and then draw it using ShapeRenderer (which is also created once) and this drops fps from 400 to 20-30. I also read  that ShapeRenderer does not caches any geometry and is used mostly for debug purposes.

Comment: @EugeneS Could you please tell how you parsed svg image and draw it using ShapeRenderer? I have similar task, but it seems that libGDX doesn't support vector graphics

Comment: Hi @dimon! I used Sovery as a base, check it out here:

http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=21333

Comment: @EugeneS Cool, thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibGDX cannot draw anything without shaders and meshes (ever since version 1.0, when OpenGL ES 1.0 support was dropped), but most of the drawing classes have built-in default shaders and use the meshes behind the scenes so you don't have to worry about them.

You also cannot call deprecated functions like `glVertex2f` since LibGDX has dropped support for OpenGL ES 1.0. (And you misunderstand the purpose of a shader if you think you can call OpenGL functions from inside a vertex or fragment shader.) The triangle tutorial you linked is outdated because it doesn't use shaders, which are now required.

I'm not sure how you determined ShapeRenderer would be too slow for your purposes. If you intend for your lines to move or you are not permanently chaining long groups of lines from end to end, then ShapeRenderer is pretty much optimized for as fast as it could possibly be done.

If your lines do not move or if you have a lot of long chains of lines that are linked end to end permanently, then you *might* get a speed boost by using the Mesh and ShaderProgram classes yourself. This is somewhat complicated if you are not very familiar with how Meshes work. You would need to construct a Mesh (and set it as static if the lines don't move) with a vertex array (and an index array if you have lots of permanently end-connected line chains). You would also need to write a shader for the ShaderProgram. Then the typical flow for drawing something would be:

```
//modify the elements of the vertex array as desired to move the lines around.

mesh.setVertices(vertices);
shaderProgram.begin();
shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_projModelView", camera.combined);
mesh.render(shaderProgram, GL20.GL_LINES);
shaderProgram.end();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I don't mind LibGDX calling Meshes and Shaders under the hood (if performance is ok), just was hoping for simple solution with OpenGL functions call (as you said Mesh is a bit complicated and makes code unreadable IMHO). 
You right, I misunderstand some concepts and your answer gives me a clue in which direction to dig.
I just wonder why it was possible to call OpenGL function without shaders in OGL ES 1.0 and not possible with 2.0?
My image is a world SVG map with lines linked permanently.
So I would be grateful if you can suggest the best way of drawing it.

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 removed features that would become redundant in the programmable function pipeline. Unlike desktop OpenGL, they decided to make it streamlined instead of fully backward compatible (since it's for mobile devices). If you look at the source code of ShapeRenderer and SpriteBatch you can figure out how to set vertices on a mesh fairly easily. In your case you may also want indices, which would cut down on the amount of mesh data. You can look up some basic OpenGL tutorials to see how they are counted.

Comment: Do you think ImmediateModeRenderer20 is a worth to try? How is it performance wise? Thank you.